# How to android kotlin volley connect REST API

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, android-volley

I want to get admin token from Magento server on REST API with Volley

I don't know to pass a parameter to API or Authentication API

I ref from Magento Document

https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.2-admin/tag/integrationcustomertoken
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/tutorials/orders/order-admin-token.html

```
binding.btnGetToken.setOnClickListener {
   getAdminToken()
}

private fun getAdminToken() {
   val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
   val url = "https://myurl.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token"

   val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
     Response.Listener<String> { response ->
       .... ?
    },
    Response.ErrorListener { error ->
       .... ?
    })
    queue.add(stringRequest)
}
```

Comment: Where are you adding a password or username to your request? It seems to be a call without parameter to an URL

Comment: I don't have use volley before
I read this syntax from google I don't know how to pass prarameter